# How do i reshape this numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

i am not able to reshape the dimensions of the this array:

```
Shape of array:
(1, 81539)

Array:
[[ 906.78302002   10.00976562   23.4375     ... 4594.27587891
49.99263      41.85557556]]
```

i am using

```
reshape(-1,36)
```

So there should be 36 columns and the needed amount of rows to store all the data from the array.

Sidenote: i am new to python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


trainData_temp = pd.read_csv('data/trainData.csv', sep=';')

numArray = np.array(trainData_temp.values).transpose()
print('Shape of array:')
print(numArray.shape)
print('Array:')
print(numArray)

numArray.reshape(-1, 36)
print(numArray)


Results:

Traceback (most recent call last):
Shape of array:
(1, 81539)
Array:
[[ 906.78302002   10.00976562   23.4375     ... 4594.27587891
49.99263      41.85557556]]

File "C:/Users/Timo/PycharmProjects/aimlHamelnProj2/csvModify.py", line 18, 
in <module>
numArray.reshape(-1, 36)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 81539 into shape (36)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using reshape in Python to reshape an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482527/using-reshape-in-python-to-reshape-an-array)

Comment: I would say that your problem is, that 81539 is not divisible by 36.

Comment: You are right, the first value is missing. I hope this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is properly because you only can reshape an array into a matrix with the same number of elements.

For example:

```py
import numpy

array = np.random.rand(3,3)
array.reshape(-1,3)
```

results in a 3x3 matrix, but

```py
array = np.random.rand(3,3)
array.reshape(-1,5)
```

would give you the same typ of error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was, that the first value of the csv file has been interpreted as the name of the column. So there was one value missing..

Thanks all for your help!